# Modal for back button

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I was wondering..does anyone here knows how can I make a modal that will pop up once browser's back button is clicked just like in Facebook.

I'm using React version 16.9.0 and tried wrapping my component to withRouter and used the this.props.history.action === "pop" inside my componentDidMount() but none working.

I've seen questions the same as mine but it seems outdated with my current react version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar use case I did it the following way. The componentDidMount is from the component which is only rendered once(In my case it's header component - it only renders once in our use case) in the app.

```
browserBackHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //do whatever is required here
};
componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = this.browserBackHandler;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering and  I tried your answer above. It did pop up my modal once I clicked the browser's back button and go back to the page again. What I am trying to do here is once I click the back button a modal will pop up asking for confirmation if the user really want to leave the page.